# Как в JOGL отрисовывать данные из массива вершин, а не из буфера в GPU?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

В java-приложении с использованием JOGL рисую например треугольник (сильно сокращенный код):

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable glad)
{
    GL3 gl = glad.getGL().getGL3();
    //подключаем буфер
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufid);
    //передаем данные в шейдер
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, str, 0);
}
```

Буфер предварительно было создан и заполнен методами glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData, т.е. данные атрибутов были размещены в видеопамяти. У метода glVertexAttribPointer нет перегрузки, кроме приведенной здесь, хотя в OPEN GL ES2 для андроида есть вариант, в котором в него можно передавать FloatBuffer и работать с данными в обычной памяти. В XNA тоже есть возможность как размещать буфера в видеопамяти и при отрисовке переключаться между ними, так и передавать для отрисовки просто массивы вершин. Как такое же делать в JOGL ?

Comment: не по теме, а что Вы пытаетесь таким образом нарисовать, если не секрет?

Comment: я здесь не пытаюсь, а успешно рисую через шейдер любые данные, которые были помещены в буфер, который я активизирую через bufid. Но это неважно, потому что код приведен только для примера вызова glVertexAttribPointer